# how to call the last row, last entered id from a table to a vba form

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-express

if my table is

```
 id      name       pwd     mob
 CL001   kiara      chopra  8809808
 CLoo2   James      Nicoles 0990889
 CL003   parineeti  pari    9094343
```

, how do i read the last entered row's ID?
into my Visual basic form?

That is, i need to read ONLY CL003.

Comment: I know the comment "SELECT * from table where id="CL003""
But i whant to read THE LAST ENTERED ID VALUE

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server - Assuming the `Id` column is an identity field, you can use:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT(‘tablename’)
```

Comment: Also how to set id column as identity field?
what if mob no. also there, Because it is also an identity column since it is unique!